# Node.js to use external JS file?

Tags: node.js, module, include, require, phpjs

Actually i'm using node-crawler under Node.js. Then i currently need to use the methods of [PHPJS](http://www.phpjs.org) (An External Javascript File). How can i add or include that JS file into NODE.JS environment?

Answer (score 2):

You can download one of the CommonJS files (here: http://phpjs.org/packages/index), save it locally and just require it like a standard NodeJS module:

var php = require('name of file');

php.md5(...)

Answer (score 0):

Just like any other file, except perhaps it will be up a few levels?:

`enter code here`require('../../path/to/whatever.js');